# SQL injection check and php throw error

Tags: php, sql

I have two question

1. is the following code a good way of practicing against SQL injection ( it seems to work OK as an insert method)
2. How would in place this error message in the full example:

   ```
   if (!mysqli_query($query,$link))
   {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
   ```

here is the full example:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "runtracker");
if (!$link)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$query="INSERT INTO userinfo (UserName) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    // Lets create the variables
    $name = $_POST['UserName'];

    // Bind the variables and execute the query
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s", $name);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    // And now we close the statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Where, exactly, are you doing anything to protect yourself against SQL injection?

Comment: @JackManey, he's using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using bound parameters is a good way to protect against SQL injection, for dynamic values in SQL queries.  For more on SQL injection, you might like my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies).

You're right that it's good to check for errors after calling API functions.  Most mysqli functions return FALSE on error, but connecting is handled slightly differently.

I also like to output the Mysqli error to a log I can read, but not to the user's browser.

Here's how I would code it:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "runtracker");
if (mysqli_connect_error())
{
    error_log("Connect error in file ".__FILE__.", line ".__LINE__.": "
      .mysqli_connect_error());
    die("Could not connect to database");
}

if (($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($link, $query)) === false) {
  error_log("Error on prepare in file ".__FILE__.", line ".__LINE__.": "
    .$mysqli->error);
  die('Error on prepare');
}

// Lets create the variables
$name = $_POST['UserName'];

// Bind the variables and execute the query
if ($stmt->bind_param("s", $name) === false) {
  error_log("Error on bind in file ".__FILE__.", line ".__LINE__.": "
    .$stmt->error);
  die('Error on bind');
}
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
  error_log("Error on execute in file ".__FILE__.", line ".__LINE__.": "
    .$stmt->error);
  die('Error on execute');
}

// And now we close the statement
$stmt->close();

echo "1 record added";

$mysqli->close();
```